# Reading text in new line from BeautilfulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I ran the command:

```
for row1 in soup.find_all('p',class_ = " cons mainText truncateThis wrapToggleStr"):
      print row1
```

Output:

[image]

When I ran the command:

```
for row1 in soup.find_all('p',class_ = " cons mainText truncateThis wrapToggleStr"):
      print row1.text
```

Output:

> At Hyderabad, IDC you have to stay late most of the time if you have to get work done on time....
> No growthMostly Verification workNot so good top management

I want it like this:

> At Hyderabad, IDC you have to stay late most of the time if you have to get work done on time....
>
> No growth
>
> Mostly Verification work
>
> Not so good top management

Please help me to get the output I want using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Please provide the output as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
row1 = soup.find_all(attrs={"class_" : " cons mainText truncateThis wrapToggleStr"})
print row1[0].text #print the first p text
for text in [ x for x in row1[1].contents if getattr(x, 'name', None) != 'br']:
    print text  #print the second p text
```

Output:

> At Hyderabad, IDC you have to stay late most of the time if you have to get work done on time
>
> No growth
>
> Mostly Verification work
>
> Not so good top management

**Details:**

`row1[1].contents` will give you:

```
[u'No growth',
 <br/>,
 u'Mostly Verification work',
 <br/>,
 u'Not so good top management']
```

Then you can filter out the text with condition `getattr(x, 'name', None) != 'br'`:

```
[u'No growth', u'Mostly Verification work', u'Not so good top management']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I am able to do my task now.

Comment: @PrashantPathak cool, please mark as correct answer if it is your solution.Thank you.